# Create HBase Table programatically in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, hbase, azure-blob-storage

I figured out, that its possible to provision a HBase database in Azure using the Blob Storage. Does anyone know how I can access, create and add items to the HBase in my blob Storage using c# code?
What I am trying afterwards is quering the data from HBase with Hive on a HDInsight cluster.

Cheers,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the [Marlin project](https://github.com/thomasjungblut/marlin) for that matter, because there is no "official" Microsoft C# client for HBase on HDInsight.

With Marlin you can create a table with a schema like this:

```
var marlin = new Marlin(ClusterCredentials.FromFile("credentials.txt"));
var testTableSchema = new TableSchema();
testTableSchema.name = "table";
testTableSchema.columns.Add(new ColumnSchema() { name = "d" });
testTableSchema.columns.Add(new ColumnSchema() { name = "f" });
marlin.CreateTable(testTableSchema);
```

It is not feature-complete yet, I just started it last weekend.

Comment: Do you know if there is any c# code or project to execute HDInisght jobs on the Azure Table Storage, too? I just found that java project http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mostlytrue/archive/2014/04/04/analyzing-azure-table-storage-data-with-hdinsight.aspx

Comment: @ProggerJoe no clue, sorry.